# Easiest way to animate a View Controller on top of another?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, viewcontroller

I have been searching for this solution for a while now, and all the tutorials are hard to follow or they are too specific, so I wanted to ask this question in general terms so it would be easy to implement. I have two separate View Controllers in Xcode (using Obj-C), and I would like to have the second View Controller be animated on top of the first by dragging down anywhere on the screen while having the first view controller stay where it is.

So far, I have tried to cram all this into one View Controller, but this is not practical as there are two different scenes and having two controllers would be a better solution.

Also, if anybody knows how to animate the first controller while the second is sliding over it that would really be a nice addition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to implement [Container-Containment view controllers](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-container-containment-sliding-menu-controller--mobile-14562). Here you use parent/child relationship and one view controller can hold many child view controllers. We move child controller to parent position based on criteria.

Hope it helps!